# MacBook Air charger doesn't light up but is charging

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

Okay so my MacBook Air is charging but the charger doesn't light up like you know that red light? How to fix this? Is it broken?

Comment: Could just be the LED in the charger. Do you have another to test with?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you have an issue with your SMC. Don't worry, it should be easy to fix, here is Apple's support document on it. [SMC Reset](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Since you have an Air, you will want to follow these steps.

> 1. Shut down the Mac.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your Mac.
> 3. Using the built-in keyboard, press Shift-Control-Option on the left side of the keyboard, then press the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all keys, then press the power button again to turn on your Mac

This can be a bit tricky to do, but try to follow the steps exactly as outlined

Good luck!

Comment: I have the same problem but resetting the SMC did nothing. Charges fine. Light on the cord is out. any other suggestions? Am I damaging the computer using it with the light out?